# crash in cocos2dx cctextureatlas EXC_??? after running for sometime on the simulator

Tags: c++, xcode, ios-simulator, opengl-es-2.0, cocos2d-x

in my cocos2dx project i've a derived class `TileMap` from `CCTMXTiledMap` class.An object of TileMap is added to a CCLayer object which is then added to a scene.
The TileMap object is initialised with a tmx file using `initWithTMXFile`.

and then i add a sprite on this TileMap object and run animation on it using `ccanimation` .
Animation runs with no problem but sometimes after about half a minute running on the `ipad` simulator it crashes showing the error in `cctextureatlas` ... `EXC_???(11)(code=0, subcode=0x0)`

The problem line is:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (GLvoid*) (start*6*sizeof(_indices[0])) );
```

This one i found on google.. but does not solve my problem:-

https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=1492

plz share some thoughts..

Comment: Share your code.Then, may be i can help you

Comment: code is very huge to mention here. If you could just tell me a hint of  the cause, that'll e very helpful